# Convert labeled faces to xml - dlib

Tags: xml, computer-vision, dlib

I've downloaded Helen Dataset for Facial Landmark Localization, there are also [annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzjgH.png) for each image. I need to create xml file like training_with_face_landmarks.xml dlib shape-predictor uses, because I want to train my own model. How can I convert it to xml? Or there is a database of labeled faces that I did not find?

Comment: you can train shape predictor without xml file. running shape_predictor_trainer::train takes vector of full_object_detection objects. so you can simply read your source dataset and construct this objects and then run training process. http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/shape_predictor_abstract.h.html#shape_predictor_trainer

Comment: shape predictor training databases were discussed here: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/359